# Disk space not freed after failed import

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have a postgres 13 cloudsql instance, in which I tried to import a database.

It failed (twice), because of an error unrelated to this issue (trying to grant permissions to a non-existing role)

The problem is, both times, the disk space used by the import was not freed entirely after the import failed. See following schema :

[image: disk usage graph]

Since then, I deleted the corresponding database, which had no effect at all.

None of the usual solutions related to reclaiming disk space (VACUUM FULL, etc) are applicable, since *there's no database to apply them to*.

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 2):

I actually found the answer while writing down this question : **WAL archives for point-in-time recovery**

Even though the import failed and was rolled back, the instance kept WAL archives.

I temporarily disabled point-in-time recovery, and the disk space was immediately freed, bringing usage back to its initial state (even lower, actually).

[image: updated disk usage graph]